# typeid of a polymorphic class, when given a pointer to a derived class, says it's a pointer to base class! why?

Tags: c++, rtti, typeid

g++ 6.3.1.

This `gdb` session illustrates that `dynamic_cast<>` does the right thing, and the compiler shows the derived `vtbl`.  `dynamic_cast<>` with the wrong derived class correctly returns `0` while it returns the correct pointer wit the right class.   Yes `typeid().name()` shows the base class (or, a mangling thereof), `P2TEBase`!  Why is this so?

```
(gdb) whatis pteExpect
type = TEBase *

(gdb) p *pteExpect
$1 = {
  _vptr.TE = 0x43cef8 <vtable for TEDerived1+16>
}

(gdb) p dynamic_cast<TEDerived2*>(pteExpect)
$2 = (TEDerived2*) 0x0

(gdb) p dynamic_cast<TEDerived1*>(pteExpect)
$3 = (TEDerived1*) 0x43cef8 <vtable for TEDerived1+16>

(gdb) l 170
170    Error( "Required %s not found", typeid( pteExpect ).name() );

(gdb) n
Reading in symbols for akstatus.c...done.
E 10.09 18:18:07.438818 main.cpp:170 Expect() - Required P2TEBase not found
```

Answer (score 2):

`typeid` is being called on the *pointer to `TEBase`* and therefore the type of this variable *truly is* a pointer to the base type, even if it happens to point to something else.

In order to log the class name of the derived class, simply use `typeid( *pteExpect ).name()` and you will see the `9TEDerived` mangled name that g++ 6.3.1 will produce.  Now, you aren't asking about the pointer (always a pointer to `TE` even if the object isn't the base class) but instead now you're asking for the thing that's pointed to, which, for a derived class of a polymorphic class, is the derived class.